# EmberJS Model Iteration by Value

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I am working on a restaurant's website as my first ember project and I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to handle the menu model.

currently the models/menu.js file reads like this:

import DS from 'ember-data';

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  price: DS.attr('number'),
  soyFree: DS.attr('string'),
  glutenFree: DS.attr('string'),
  addOnName: DS.attr('string'),
  addOnPrice: DS.attr('number'),
  type: DS.attr('string'),
  isAppetizer: Ember.computed('type', function(){
    return this.get('type') == 'Appetizer';
  }),
  isBreakfast: Ember.computed('type', function(){
    return this.get('type') == 'Breakfast';
  })
});
```

My menu template file is:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
  <h2>Menu</h2>
  <h2 class="text-center">Appetizers</h2>
  {{#each model as |menu|}}
    {{#if menu.isAppetizer}}

      <p>
        <span><strong>{{menu.name}}</strong> - <em>{{menu.description}}</em> - {{menu.price}}</span>
        {{#if session.isAuthenticated}}<button class="btn btn-danger" {{action "deleteMenuItem" menu}}>Delete</button>{{/if}}
      </p>
    {{/if}}

  {{/each}}
  <h2 class="text-center">Breakfast</h2>
  {{#each model as |menu|}}
    {{#if menu.isBreakfast}}

      <p>
        <span><strong>{{menu.name}}</strong> - <em>{{menu.description}}</em> - {{menu.price}}</span>
        {{#if session.isAuthenticated}}<button class="btn btn-danger" {{action "deleteMenuItem" menu}}>Delete</button>{{/if}}
      </p>
    {{/if}}

  {{/each}}
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

As you can see I am having to reiterate through all of the menu model entries for each section (Appetizers / Breakfast). Is there a way with ember that I can only iterate over the specific item type for each #each block. 
ie.,

```
{{#each model.type == 'Appetizer'}} 
  Fill the appetizer section 
 {{/each}}
```

Here is my route file is:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return this.store.findAll('menu');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can return the required value from model hook and access it using `model.appetizerMenu` for Appetizer menu.

```
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('menu').then((result) => {
            return {
                appetizerMenu: result.filterBy('isAppetizer', true),
                breakFastMenu: result.filterBy('isBreakfast', true),
            }
        });
    }
```

2.you can have computed property in controller.

```
appetizerMenu: Ember.computed.filterBy('model','isAppetizer',true),
breakFastMenu: Ember.computed.filterBy('model','isBreakfast',true),
```

3.Further you can simplify that you dont need computed property in the model for every type like currently you are having.
You can use `type` attribute alone for filtering whenever is required.

```
    appetizerMenu: Ember.computed.filterBy('model','type','Appetizer'),
    breakFastMenu: Ember.computed.filterBy('model','type','Breakfast'),
```

4.If you want more shopisticated helper like you suggested `{{#each model.type == 'Appetizer'}}` then you might be interested in [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers)

Comment: ah awesome thats what i was trying to do but had my syntax wrong thanks!

Comment: getting a build error trying to use your first suggestion:5 |     return this.store.findAll('menu').then(result => {
   6 |       appetizerMenu: result.filterBy('isAppetizer', true),
>  7 |         breakFastMenu: result.filterBy('isBreakfast', true)
     |                      ^
   8 |     });
   9 |   }
  10 | });

Comment: try `then((result) => {`

Comment: Unexpected token, expected ; for the colon in front of breakFastMenu prop

Comment: I was missing `,` after `'isBreakfast'` . I updated this with my answer

Comment: i noticed that as well but still getting the same error

Comment: We need to return the result inside `then`,I updated my answer. I am little confused with the es6 features..sorry for the trouble.